# Why do I get Permission denied error while trying to root Android Lucid 4G version 4.0.4 device?

Tags: rooting

I am trying to root an Android Lucid 4G version 4.0.4 device. But it gives the following error:

```
[*] Device found.
rm failed for /data/bootlogo/bootlogopid, No such file or directory
link failed No such file or directory
[*] Rebooting...
[*] Waiting for reboot...
/system/bin/sh: cannot create /data/local.prop: Permission denied
[*] Rebooting again...
[*] Waiting for reboot...
```

Following is the screenshot of the error messages:

[image: error message]

I followed [this tutorial to root the device](http://theunlockr.com/2010/10/11/how-to-root-your-android-phone-superoneclick-method/). I've also updated the driver to ADB driver interface but it's still not working.

Comment: It would help to know which instructions you were following, and at which step this error happened.

Comment: I'll find the instructions ASAP . I was following the steps and the step where it failed was where it said to click run.bat I believe, which I did and then it ran the prompt and showed this

Comment: HERE IS WHAT I FOLLOWED http://theunlockr.com/2010/10/11/how-to-root-your-android-phone-superoneclick-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root method in the link is not compatible with android 4.0.4.
before you root - be sure you know what you are doing.

To root the Lucid 4G on 4.0.4 you can try the following method:

- http://theunlockr.com/2013/06/16/how-to-root-the-lg-lucid-4g-bin4ry-method/

But choose "Xperia Root by cubeundcube" instead of "Normal mode"

Comment: Where could I have my password when I restore it to root it I'm using the second method btw......I hit restore and it said it ended

Comment: Gotcha it seemed to work then I unplugged it by accident seems like its a working method thanks for the help!

Comment: I have backed up everything and the first one seems more complicated I'll try it now

Comment: I can't find the link for the root download in the first method nvm found it but is it saver then the second ?

Comment: Okay so for the first one there's 6 options which one should I choose Xperia root by cubeundcube 2) new standard root 3)old 4)old special g) good glass

Comment: Alright I went with the old one and it said it was successful and it restarted it and said waiting for device to show up again and right when it did the prompt went away /crashed should I just re do it (Also it did say In between texts ping is not a command)

Comment: Yes it just crashed didn't even see press key to continue

Comment: Tried the cube method worked smoothly I got the super app and got root checker and it confirms my device has root access! Thank you very Much :)